# how can I put different code or not editable code when ctrl+shift+i I am doing in browser

Tags: javascript, java, css, html

I have some Html code Like:

```
Enter UserName <input type="text" name="user"><br>
Enter Password <input type="password" name="pass">
```

when I running this code it displaing on browser but while I am doing ctrl+shift+i html code is coming like this:

```
<input name="pass" type="password">
```

but if I change this type runtime as a **"text"**  then my password is visible.

please tell me some solution how I can change or put different code in runtime that shows not changeable after ctrl+shift+i.

Comment: Enter UserName <input type="text" name="user"><br>
        Enter Password <input type="password" name="pass">

Comment: It is, unfortunately, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way by applying the same security attribute to input box of any type to show value as the password.

```css
input.password-input {
    text-security: disc;
-webkit-text-security: disc;
-moz-text-security: disc;
}
```

```html
Enter UserName <input type="text" name="user"><br> Enter Password <input type="password" class="password-input" name="pass">
```

If you change input type then text still can't visible.

But **caution**, someone could simply "inspect element" in Chrome and change the css element from "disc" to "none" and real text would be seen clear as day.

Comment: input.password-input {
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
}Where I put this code in my html code this is my html code<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>ControlShiftI Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        Enter UserName <input type="text" name="user"><br>
        Enter Password <input type="password" name="pass"> 

    </body>
</html>

Comment: this is nothing related to `HTML` give your password input `class` and then add `CSS`.

Comment: after adding this also in browser if I do ctrl+shift+i and change type password to text it will show my password

Comment: do you added the css i provided in your css file?

Comment: no kept like inside <style> attribute like this <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>ControlShiftI Example</title>
        <style>
       input.password-input {
        -webkit-text-security: disc;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
        
Enter UserName <input type="text" name="user"><br> Enter Password <input type="password" class="password-input" name="pass">

    </body>
</html>

Comment: which browser you are checking